# Como ocultar numa URL o texto que aparece após o meu domínio?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, url, spring-mvc

Tenho uma aplicação Java utilizando Spring MVC.

Suponhamos que a minha aplicação tenho o domínio www.meusistema.com.br

Conforme o usuário navega, outras urls são geradas, exemplo:

- www.meusistema.com.br/acessarConta
- www.meusistema.com.br/cadastros/recuperarSenha
- www.meusistema.com.br/cadastrar?tipo=1

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de ocultar o que aparece depois da barra (/), e portanto o meu usuário sempre navegar apenas vendo www.meusistema.com.br

Existe alguma forma de ocultar esse restante da url? A aplicação utiliza Spring MVC mas a solução pra isso não necessariamente precisa usar esse framework... Minhas telas são em JSP, então posso usar javascript, ajax, jquery etc.

Comment: Não é aconselhável fazer isso. Um exemplo disso é se o usuário quiser passar a URL para um amigo, como fica ? Ou quiser guardar, não tiver Javascript ativo no Browser (oque não é impossível) ? Fora que o Google não irá listar as outras páginas do seu site, o que acredite, gera uma grande perca.

Comment: A ideia é justamente essa, o usuário não passar e ter acesso às urls. Pelo spring, eu já coloquei perfis de usuário pra que ele não tenha acesso às páginas que o perfil dele não permite. Mas eu tenho alguns casos em que não existe restrição de perfil, mas não queremos que o usuário tenha a url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionei o problema mudando todos os forms do html para POST, definindo então no Controller o que aparece na URL.

Comment: como vc solucionou o problema ??

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode mapear o controller pra "/" e usar o [ViewResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) para lidar com cada view.

Neste caso o controller teria que redirecionar a requisição para cada view apropriada, retornando nomes de views diferentes.